# How to make handwriting panel stay still in Windows 10? How to pin it?

Tags: windows-10, handwriting

I have a mouse in my hand, I don't need handwriting panel try to jump since I can drag it myself. Also I don't need it disappear when it thinks it is not needed, I would like to decide myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can dock the handwriting panel to the bottom of the screen:

- click/tap on the keyboard settings menu button
- click/tap on the handwriting icon
- click/tap on the docked icon

[image]

Source: Microsoft's [Get to know the touch keyboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-to-know-the-touch-keyboard-004f3d67-855b-27f0-6f7c-d5145f691181).

Comment: Would like to stay as a window...

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft didn't think of it.